# Angular Custom Validators. How to validate a form field using a given Promise?

Tags: angular, typescript, promise, customvalidator

I need to validate a form field using a method which returns a Promise. But it never returns the error because Promises are asynchronous.

This is my validator:

```
static email(usersService: UsersService): ValidatorFn {

  return (control: AbstractControl):{ [key: string]: boolean | null } => {
    const email = control.value;
    if (email) {
      usersService.validateUsername(email).then(
        (result) => { return result.username ? {emailExists: true} : null }
      )
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }}
```

This is my UsersService method

```
validateUsername(username: string): Promise<{"username": string}> {
  return this.httpClient.post('/users/username_validation', {"username": username}).pipe(
    map((body: {"username": string}) => body),
  ).toPromise()}
```

Comment: Have you looked at `AsyncValidatorFn`?

Comment: @KurtHamilton I have looked at it. Still the same issue

Comment: `AsyncValidatorFn` - as the name suggests - is designed to do async validation. Can you post your attempt to use it so that we can see why it's not working for you.

Comment: I tried the same I posted just changing the return types

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All I needed to do is use AsyncValidator like this:

**validator.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AbstractControl, AsyncValidator, ValidationErrors } from '@angular/forms';
import { Observable} from 'rxjs';

import { UsersService } from "@app/users/users.service";


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class EmailValidator implements AsyncValidator {

  constructor( private usersService: UsersService ) { }

  validate( control: AbstractControl): Promise<ValidationErrors> | Observable<ValidationErrors> {

    const email = control.value;
    if (email) {
      return this.usersService.validateUsername(email).then(
        (result) => { 
          console.log(result)
          return result.username ? {emailExists: true} : null 
        }
      )
    } else {
      return null;
    }

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you missing the **return** for your promise, this should work

```
if (email) {
  return usersService.validateUsername(email).then( // here in this line
    (result) => { return result.username ? {emailExists: true} : null }
  )
}
```

You can refactor it to

```
 return (control: AbstractControl):Promise<ValidationErrors | null> | Observable<ValidationErrors | null> => 
 {
  const email = control.value;
  return (email &&  usersService.validateUsername(email).then( 
    (result) => { return result.username ? {emailExists: true} : null }
  )) || null;
 }
```

Comment: Still the same issue